# Let users add my email address as forwarding email

Tags: email, gmail

We run an automation service, so basically we need to login into users, but sometimes website ask for pin the code. Which comes at user email address so we can't login until user provide us the email. But If user automate automate email forwarding to our address we can login and continue users task.

We are trying gmail, but the problem with gmail is when user add us a forwarding email, we need to confirm by clicking the URL google sent to our email address, we can't do that, If I login with IMAP in code. The question is how do I automate it? Is there a way to do this or not?